# Angular 2 query any element in the document from directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I need to query elements in the document using `querySelector` since I can't provide any reference to the elements that are not in the same component as the element that the directive is being used on.

The problem is that no matter what life cycle hook I use, the directive can't find the elements with a certain class that is outside of the component that the directive it used on.

I've tried `AfterContentInit` and `AfterViewInit` but no luck.

Here's a simple example:

Component 1:

```
<div class="class1"></div>
<div myDirective [classesToQuery]="['class1', 'class2']"></div>
```

Component 2:

```
<div class="class2">Hero</div>
```

The directive:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.waypoint = this.getWaypointTotal();
}

queryElementsByClasses(): any[] {

  let queriedElements: any[] = [];

  for (let query of this.classesToQuery) {

    const element: any = document.querySelector('.' + query);

    if (element) {
      queriedElements.push(element);
    }
  };

  return queriedElements;
}

getWaypointTotal(): any {

  let total: number = 0;
  let elements: any[] = this.queryElementsByClasses();

  for (let element of elements) {

    const height: number = element.offsetHeight;

    total = total + height;
  };

  return total;
}
```

Comment: It's not going work no matter which lifecycles you are using in the directive, it's because the component 1 and 2 has different lifecycle than your directive lifecycle. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Chybie I need to check the height of a bunch of different elements and then calc a total. And based on the total something should happen.

Comment: alright, probably u can provide you HTML template on the main component that use these 2 components?

Comment: Here is an example of calculating child component height. Demo: https://ng-musing.firebaseapp.com/same-height, Github: https://github.com/chybie/ng-musing/tree/master/src/app/same-height